# Add additional Text in a SelectListItem

Tags: model-view-controller

Is it possible to add an additional `Text` in a `SelectListItem?

Example:

```
SelectListItem { Text = "Deduction", Value = "100", Text2 = "SomeText"}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Short answer is no. (what would you want it for anyway?)

Comment: Oh thanks for your answer @StephenMuecke , i'll think for another solution for what i need :)